# how to get all headings tags values using js

Tags: javascript

am trying to get the text content of all `h` tags in my html page using js.
but my code stops working when a specific `h` tag doesn't exist. i couldn't succeed writing the if statement testing if an `h` tag doesn't exit do smth.

my html :

```
<h1> <a href="" >just a link </a>HTML testing File</h1>
<h2>Another text</h2>
<h4>An h4 text</h4>
```

my js :

```
window.onload = word;
function word () {

var h=["h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6"];
var headings = [];
for (var i =0; i<h.length ;i++)
{


    if (document.getElementsByTagName(h[i]))
{
    headings[i] = document.querySelector(h[i]).textContent;
  alert(headings[i] );

}
else

{ alert(h[i]+"doesn't exist");
    }

}

}
```

Any help , thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply if condition for validate the `heading[i]`. like this

```
if(headings[i]){
      console.log(headings[i].textContent);
      }
```

```js
window.onload = word;

function word() {
  var h = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"];
  var headings = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName(h[i])) {
      headings[i] = document.querySelector(h[i]);
      if (headings[i]) {
        console.log(headings[i].textContent);
      }
    } else {
      alert(h[i] + "doesn't exist");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> <a href="">just a link </a>HTML testing File</h1>
<h2>Another text</h2>
<h4>An h4 text</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery you could use the code below

```
 $("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").each(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: The OP asked how to do it using Javascript. There may be a particular reason they're not using jQuery.

Comment: @Soviut yes I understand, but stackoverflow is not just for answering questions but to follow better practice also. I was guiding her. Using jquery in any application is not a sin. Its bad to downvote for everything that you don't like

Comment: I downvoted because there are all sorts of reasons people need to use vanilla javascript and you simply said "use jquery" not "if you are using jquery". One is a conditional solution, the other is an imperative.

Comment: @Soviut I understand and take your suggestion and you have full right to comment also but I am only concerned with your downvote. I could have updated my asnwer.  Its the person who asked has to say if it helped him or not. Since we have an option to downvote doesn't mean that we have to hit that everywhere.People like you always has to guide new users, but should not demotivate

Comment: @Soviut In your comments and down vote i don't see any enthusiasm for you to solve his issue. Otherwise you could have updated my answer. If you want to improve the quality of my answer, yes you can comment and if I am not updating in another 30 mins yes you could go ahead and give down vote. That way I would say you are a great mentor. But now I evaluate you as a person who just interested in giving down votes to emerging users like me. Its soo bad, please don't do it for another person again.

Comment: I downvoted you because of how you phrased your answer, not because you suggested jquery. Next time, don't tell the OP to "use jquery", let them know that your solution simply requires jquery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144115/discussion-between-kiran-b-and-soviut).

Comment: I did update your answer, I fixed your unformatted code, another reason to downvote. Trust me, one downvote is not the end of the world.

Comment: @Soviut yes your points are valid and I agree with your down vote. You are a great person with great attitude and a good mentor. Please do the same always and thanks a lot for clarifications. This will definitely help me to improve.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` condition always returns `true`

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName(h[i]))
```

`getElementsByTagName()` returns an array. In case of no occurrences it will return an empty array and `if ([])` is `true`

Change it to

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName(h[i]).length > 0)
```